# Nokia 5110 Screen Pixel by Pixel

Tags: programming, lcd

I have got this LCD screen
[image]

I'd like to be able to decide every pixel status of the screen. Do I need to work directly with the buffer or is there another method?

Comment: Create a byte buffer where you draw everything (and check pixel values) and flush it to the display after changes. This way you can also implement double buffering to avoid any flickering during animations.

Answer (score 5):

The 5110 Nokia LCD display is based on [PCD8544](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/LCD/Monochrome/Nokia5110.pdf). It is not possible to read the device display memory. The controller has only serial data input.

Typically a graphical device driver for that display will use an offscreen bitmap (buffer). To check the pixel status you would need to check the status in the offscreen bitmap.

Some device drivers use only text and copy font bitmap directly to the display memory. In that case you cannot check the status of the pixel (if the text is not buffered).